# Typescript compiler error Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target on API call

Tags: angularjs, typescript

This is my method to call Web API, the line that starts this.$http.post`<Boolean>`; throws the error Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.:

```
updateShowHold = (show: boolean): ng.IPromise<FilterDto> =>
    {
        var deferred = this.$q.defer();

        this.$http.post<boolean>("/api/1.0/Bidding/Filter/Hold/Update/" + show).then(response =>
        {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }).catch(reason =>
        {
            deferred.reject(reason);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

This is my Web API method:

```
[Route("Hold/Update/{showHold}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> UpdateHold(bool showHold)
    {
        var filter = await _filterService.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync( f => f.CrewId == CrewId );
        if(filter != null)
        {
            filter.ShowHold = showHold;
            await _filterService.UpdateAsync( filter, filter.FilterId );

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling post without @data. The signature for post is

```
post<T>(url: string, data: any, config?: IRequestShortcutConfig): IHttpPromise<T>;
```

You should use **get** if you're not posting data, or at least

```
this.$http.post<boolean>("/api/1.0/Bidding/Filter/Hold/Update/" + show,{})
```

I question your implementation, for example why require POST if you're not sending data, and your response - how is that formed?

This should get you started, I recommend cleaning up your code a bit for example no need to use deferred and incomplete typing.

```
updateShowHold = (show: boolean): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    return this.$http.post("/api/1.0/Bidding/Filter/Hold/Update/" + show,{})
        .then((response: any): any => {
            return response.data;
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I updated to your suggestion and it works perfectly. I am not able to up vote yet, too new to SO.